# Android Emulator can not load native library

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a project about stitching images and I use opencv 2.4.5 and java. All my codes are java codes and it is running perfect when it's a java project. I transfered my code to android, imported opencv-245.jar and opencv_java245.dll to my project then I configured build path. But when my code comes to System.loadLibrary(...):

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat image1= Highgui.imread( imgs.get(0).toString() , 1);
Mat image2= Highgui.imread( imgs.get(1).toString() , 1);
...
```

It gives an error and couldn't load opencv native library(opencv_java245.dll). I searched it on the internet and read many things but didn't find an answer. Most of them were about android ndk but I don't use it and my codes are not c++. I tried to use System.load(path) but it failed again. Please give me any advice. Thanks.

UPDATE:
Stack trace:

```
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2704)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2699)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  ... 11 more
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java245: findLibrary returned null
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at org.myproject.stitching_android.SDCardToGridView.onClickStitching(SDCardToGridView.java:90)
06-23 18:23:37.884: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Wait, what? you are trying to load a dll to Android? Don't you know that [a dll is just Windows-compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)? You cannot load it on Android

Comment: It called native library for java and android. We can use it with Android NDK but all my codes are java and its running perfect when i use it in java project but android project... I guess i dont know something or missing something about it.

Comment: Because you are not compiling it right. If it runs in a Java project (outside Android emulator) then it will not work in Android, just because the instruction sets are different (Android->ARM/RISC, PC->CISC)

Comment: I just added opencv-245.jar and edited Native Library Location (C:\opencv\build\java\x86) in this jar for java project and everything worked fine. There is only opencv_java245.dll in C:\opencv\build\java\x86 so i tried to import it android project and show it like the same but i failed.  is there a way to load this library in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are trying to load a dll on an Android device. A DLL is [a Microsoft Windows only library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library), it can't be loaded by an Android app.

---

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1108]: Library '/data/data/org.myproject.stitching_android/lib/opencv_java245.dll' not found
```

Means that your app can't find the file, even if it finds the file it won't be able to load it because Android doesn't support DLLs

Answer (score -1):

Android is a Linux derivative and Linux dynamic libraries has .so extension